# Mitigating weaknesses in RC4

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, rc4

I've been researching RC4 and implementing it, and I was wondering, from the perspective of a cryptographer (a real one, not a fake one like me), what could be added to the RC4 algorithm to improve on its security?

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicate questions… especially, when you’ve already asked the same thing. Posting duplicates of **[your other, recent question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/37789/12164)** is not constructive. Besides, **[the same question was already asked in the past](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3643/is-there-a-way-to-make-rc4-arcfour-secure-or-is-it-completely-broken)** (with much more detail) and has received in-deep answers that handle RC4’s weaknesses, as well as potential options (if any) to fix things. You might want to take a look at it.